# Prettier Increase Line height VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

How can i increase line height in prettier . Prettier only allows 1 line height distance between code. I want to increase line height for some code only not all.

for example :

code 1

code 2  (3 line spacing here which prettier doesn't allow and sets it to one .If i save the file.)

I tried google search and chatgpt and couldn't find the option for line Height.

Comment: related docs (nothing particularly interesting): https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#empty-lines